# Background Images with width 100% center to fix position

Tags: css, header, position, background-image

First of all I would like to thank you all for your answers all this time. I have found a lot of solutions from my projects through the site as a student as well as a working.

I search a lot before asking this question but I couldn't find a working solution.

Sorry for the title. Couldn't think a better one.

I try to develop a site and I have a problem with the header. The main page container has a fix size of 1024px and the content inside is restricted to 960px. Only the header and the footer takes the whole wight of the window.

I have two images: The first one is 2000x250 (the buildings behind) and the second one is 2000x58 (the languages with the houses).Let's name them img_A and img_B respectively. I want both of them to take the whole wight of screen depending the user resolution (like the footer) but scale it also to responding to the height.

The problem is that I want no matter the screen resolution is, the img_B to be centered inside the 1024px so the ES button will be at the end of main page (1024px) so the logo that is center with margin 0 auto; don't cover the houses.

Here some images to illustrate better what I am asking.

Wrong (1920x1200):

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/577/headerwrong.jpg/

Right (1680x1050):

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/20/headercorrect.jpg/

Here is my css code:

```
#header{
    height: 140px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(images/background_home.jpg) center center no-repeat;
}

#header .language_banner{
    background: transparent url(images/header_en.png) right bottom no-repeat;
}

#header .logo{
    display:block; 
    width:242px; 
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top: 63px;
}
```

and the html code:

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="language_banner">
        <div class="logo">
            <img alt="athens insiders" src="<?php    bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>/images/logo.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve, but I *think* you want to try looking at (and adding!) the background-size css (and maybe background-clip) property to your #header (or wherever), after you define the background.

Note the support isn't there in earlier versions of IE, so you may need another work around if you're going for universal compatibility.

Comment: Thanks! It's a bit difficult for me to explain it in English what I am trying to say. The background-position:cover work fine with the img_A background image. But I have the same problem with the img_B. I can't position it in the same place no matter the resolution. Depending the resolution the image starts at different point and ends in different. I want always the ES link on the image to be at the end of the content page that the explorer has auto center. Maybe this can illustrate better: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/593/headerwrong2.jpg/ .Sorry for my English.

Comment: Have you thought about creating the houses and languages as absolutely positioned elements, and putting them where you like / need to within the other background? Strikes me as being a much simpler way to have more control over what you're trying to do...

Comment: Thanks for your help! See this site : http://athensinsiders.com/. The guy have done the same I want with one background image. I want the same. If you re size the window you will see that the background is in the same place every time you re size the window. I tried based on his code but I couldn't do it. Nice idea about creating separate images.

Comment: Right - on the site you're looking at, there's two separate header images, one for EN and one for ES. See here:

[EN](http://athensinsiders.com/v1/assets/img/header_back.png)
[ES](http://athensinsiders.com/v1/assets/img/header_back_es.jpg)

The logo in the center is a [separate image](http://athensinsiders.com/v1/assets/img/top_logo.png) that's centered using CSS so it's always in the middle, with:

`display: block;
width: whateverpx;
margin: 0 auto;`

This sits it right in the center, regardless. As the background images is always centered, the ES and EN buttons are always in the same place.

Comment: ...To continue, both the buttons for EN and ES and empty anchors, sized to cover the images on the background, with display block, and positioned absolutely using the center of the page as an initial reference. Make sense?

Comment: Thanks! I also have a separate image for the logo that is center with the way you provide. The problem was the backgournd img_B. Due to your help I realize and manage to center the background image. So the big problem was solved but still the logo image over the houses. So I realize that I had to photoshop the image a bit and bring it to the left and fill the empty space to the right. Thanks a lot! Your help was crucial.